# How do I open Markdown files from the Dropbox app?

Tags: dropbox

When I try to open a Markdown file in the Dropbox app, it tells me to "Please download an app that can open this file."

I tried downloading [MarkDrop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.keepzero.markdrop), but that seems to only sync within its own folder.

Any suggested apps that support this?

Comment: The whole point of Markdown is that they're just plain text files that can be read in anything, and the the formatting is just an expansion of what people used to use in plain text communications like Usenet. What are you calling your files? Mine are name as *.txt files and can be opened in almost anything, but look nicer when opened in a Markdown compatible editor.

Comment: @GAThrawn _Unfortunately_ there is a strong trend to use anything but .txt for markdown files. GitHub for instance will not interpret .txt files as being formatted using markdown (and will therefore not pretty print it), you must use one of the other "markdown" file extensions.

Comment: I use the `.md` extension which is why it doesn't open in text editors. I'd rather keep it so other applications know that it's markdown.

Comment: @w3d no one should assume `.txt` is markdown-formatted because most of the time it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

[Draft](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mvilla.draft) can open Markdown files with `.md` and `.markdown` extensions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to exist anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

[MarkDawn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.versionupsoft.markdawn).

If you open a `.md` file in the Dropbox app it'll let you to open it with it.

It has been pointed out that currently (as of 2013-04-18) **MarkDawn only works as a viewer**.

Comment: Do you use MarkDawn as an editor? The preview pane does not appear to update for me and neither does it sync back to your dropbox (as other ordinary text editors do)?

Comment: The preview works for me but you're right about it only working as a viewer. I've never even tried using it for editing. Oh well.

Comment: Seems it's not available anymore

Comment: Can you please update for me that answer.  I have exactly the same question and tried a dozen of apps. MarkdownX was good but does no more work

Answer (score 2):

I found a good web application to view and edit markdown-formatted files - **[StackEdit](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/)**.

You can integrate it with **Dropbox** and **Google Drive** and use it to open any of your text files. It doesn't matter if were `.md`, `.txt,` or something else.

Comment: Since StackEdit is not an android app, I don't see how you can get it to automatically open `.md` files.